# Why is javascript class property is showing as Proxy object in getter

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

Following is the javascript code I wrote for one of the lightning-web-component. When I am trying to use getter function in HTML, the component is throwing an error **Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**. I debugged the code and found that type of **this.studentGradedCourses** is Proxy{} and it has properties:

```
[[Handler]]: ReactiveProxyHandler
[[Target]]: Object
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

I don't know what happening and why it is turning into a Proxy object.
According to documentation, no error should be thrown.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about.
I am stuck on this for hours, please help me.
JS code:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from "lwc";
import getStudentCompletedCourses from "@salesforce/apex/StudentController.getStudentCompletedCourses";

export default class StudentProfile extends LightningElement {
  @track
  studentId = "0036300000TlkEIAAZ";
  @wire(getStudentCompletedCourses, { Id: "$studentId" })
  studentGradedCourses;

  get gradedCoursesLength() {
    return this.studentGradedCourses.data.length;
  }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <b>Course Grade Of D/F: {gradedCoursesLength}</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not conditionally rendering your data. I think that's the problem. Notice that when your component loads, it doesn't immediately retrieve and assign the value to the `studentGradedCourses` property yet. It is an asynchronous process.

Try to surround your `<b>` tag with a `<template>` tag, like:

```html
<template if:true={propIsDefined}>
    <b>{prop.data.length}</b>
</template>
```

```js
get propIsDefined () {
    return this.prop !== undefined && this.prop.data !== undefined
}
```

When you use `console.log` to show what the property is, you'll get the Lightning Locker's Proxy object. It is enabled by default, and is a security feature. If you want to display the value of it though, you can use this little gimmick:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prop))
```